# Reducing code and using .off after using a feature

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are two problems that I have with my Javascript, first I think function is very long and I would like to find out if there is a way to reduce it, the problem is it needs to be working together as all of this Javascript is allowing to edit a page.

2nd problem is that when I change font and/or choose font size it will change both things, so for example if I change font-size in one div and then I want to change font-family for other it will change font-size and font-family, so what should I do so that after each edit it turns off click function but if pressed again it will add it back so that feature can be used again, so basically only one feature can be used at the time.

```
$(function() {
        $('#cp4').colorpicker().on('changeColor', function(e) {
            $('#content-link2')[0].style.backgroundColor = e.color.toString(
                'rgba');
        });
    });
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#startEdit").click(function () {
    if ($("#startEdit").on('click')) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
    var font;
    $("#fonts1").on("change", function(){
        font = $(this).val();
    });
    $("#content-link2").on("click", "*", function() {
        $(this).css('font-family',font);
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    var font;
    $("#googlefonts1").on("change", function(){
        font = $(this).val();
    });
    $("#content-link2").on("click", "*", function() {
        $(this).css('font-family',font);
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fsize;
    $("#fontsizes1").on("change", function(){
        fsize = $(this).val();
    });
    $("#content-link2").on("click", "*", function() {
        $(this).css('font-size',fsize);
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    var color;
    $("#colorChoice").on('input', function(){
        color = $(this).val();
    });
    $('#content-link2').on('click', '*', function() {
        $(this).css('background',color);
  });
});
    } else {
          $( "#content-link2" ).off( "click" );
    }
  });
```

### });

```
<div class="features form-group">
            <input class="filestyle form-control margin images"  data-input="false" type="file" data-buttonText="Upload Logo"
            data-size="sm" data-badge="false" onchange="readURL(this);" />
            <!--<button onClick=" updateDatabase(this);"</button>-->
            <button style="display: none" class="form-control margin btn btn-primary" id="showColor">Show Colors</button>
            <button style="display: none" class="form-control margin btn btn-primary" id="hideColor">Hide Colors</button>
            <input style="display: none" class="btn btn-default form-control margin" type="color" id="colorChoice">
            <a style="display: none" href="#" class="btn btn-default form-control margin" id="cp4">Background</a>
            <button style="display: none" onclick="$('#fonts1').bfhfonts({font: 'Arial'})" id="fontsShow" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin">Load Fonts</button>
            <button style="display: none" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin" id="fontsHide">Hide Fonts</button>
            <select style="display: none" data-font="Arial" id="fonts1" class="form-control margin"></select>
            <button style="display: none" onclick="$('#googlefonts1').bfhgooglefonts({font: 'Lato'})" id="googleShow" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin">Google fonts</button>
            <button style="display: none" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin" id="googleHide">Hide Google</button>
            <select style="display: none" id="googlefonts1" class="form-control margin"></select>
            <button style="display: none" onclick="$('#fontsizes1').bfhfontsizes({fontsize: '12'})" id="sizeShow" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin">Load font size</button>
            <button style="display: none" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin" id="sizeHide">Hide font size</button>
            <select style="display: none" id="fontsizes1" class="form-control margin"></select>
            <button style="display: none" class="form-control margin btn btn-default" id="finishEdit">Done</button>
            <button class="form-control margin btn btn-default" id="startEdit">Edit</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: 1) All the click definitions can go into the same document.ready() function, no need to create a new one for each click handler. 2) For the css it's probably better to use classes and just switch the class on and off when needed istead of settings specific rules on individual elements.

Comment: "I think function is very long" - you have 5 functions that are $(document).ready handlers. Which function are you referring to?

Comment: @Igor all of it really, if you have a look it's 1 big function and inside it there are 5 functions.

Comment: How could I modify it so after changing font-size or clicking on another button would reset previous binding element? but would allow in future to use it again

Comment: If you can please answer my question just above, because basically if I change font-size but I don't want to edit it anymore however I will want to edit it in the future how could I use .off event clicker effectively to unbind and bind these buttons again

Comment: `if ($("#startEdit").on('click')) {` - what does this `if` check? http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Basically what I tried to do is if #startEdit is pressed, bind all click events and when #finishEdit is pressed, unbind them, however that doesn't work very well so I must have done something wrong, you can thing of it that when #startEdit is pressed, allow editing and when #finishEdit is pressed not allow any editing

Comment: @Igor saying it won't be called is incorrect, it is however redundant

Comment: @Igor you have misread the docs. That statement is regarding `on('ready'` which is not the same

Comment: So is anyone able to provide solution my comment above?